# window.location.hash always shows empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In my phonegap application i updated my datas for that i have the following code in that i got the `window.location.hash`(* indicate error line) value will be empty.

```
function init() {

    $("#homePage").live("pageshow", function() {
    getDatas();
});

$("#editPage").live("pageshow", function() {
    ***var loc = window.location.hash;***
    alert("loc" + loc);
    if(loc.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
        var qs = loc.substr(loc.indexOf("?")+1, loc.length);
        var detailId = qs.split("=")[1];
        $("#editFormSubmitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("select id,name,age,city,occupation from nameDetail where id=?", [detailId], function(tx, results) {
                $("#mId").val(results.rows.item(0).id);
                $("#mName").val(results.rows.item(0).name);
                $("#mAge").val(results.rows.item(0).age);
                $("#mCity").val(results.rows.item(0).city);
                $("#mOccupation").val(results.rows.item(0).occupation);
                $("#editFormSubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        }, dbErrHandler);
    } else {
    alert("empty");
        $("#editFormSubmitButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

}

function getDatas() {
dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("select id,name,age,city,occupation,date from nameDetail order by date desc", [], renderEntries, dbErrHandler);
}, dbErrHandler);
}

function renderEntries(tx, results) {
 if (results.rows.length == 0) {
    $("#mainContent").html("<p>Don't have any Details</p>");
} else {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        s += "<li><a href='addEdit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id + "'>" +results.rows.item(i).name + "</a></li>";
        alert("" + s);
    }
//alert(S);
    $("#noteTitleList").html(s);
    $("#noteTitleList").listview("refresh");
}
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Names</title>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">


<div data-role="page" id="homePage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Names</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="mainContent">  
        <ul data-role="listview" id="noteTitleList"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
        <a href="addEdit.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add Note</a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and addEdit.html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="editPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Details</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <form id="addEditForm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="mId" id="mId" value="">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="mName" id="mName"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mAge">Age</label>
                <input name="mAge" id="mAge"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mCity">City</label>
                <input name="mCity" id="mCity"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="mOccupation">Occupation</label>
                <input name="mOccupation" id="mOccupation"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="submit" id="editFormSubmitButton" value="Save Note">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Return Home</a>
        <input type="button"  data-role="button" id="sync" name="sync" value="Sync" data-icon="arrow-d"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

how to solve this some body help to solve this...

**EDIT :**

issue solved using this one.
[solution link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088712/window-location-hash-always-shows-empty/21199808#21199808)

Comment: Can you post your html part here ?

Comment: Did you tried adding addEdit.html#editPage?

Comment: @ChinnuR no i didn't try i am new to jquery and javscript..

Comment: this line doing the same job rigth s += "<li><a href='addEdit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id + "'>" +results.rows.item(i).name + "</a></li>";

Comment: @ChinnuR please edit my post how to do this...

Comment: you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#) to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash between these two modes.

For example, a link to a page containing multiple internal pages would look like this:
<a href="multipage.html" rel="external">Multi-page link</a>  REF: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: @ChinnuR i tried rel and data-ajax but still same...

Comment: Can you ad this in you html and click the button <a href="addEdit.html#main" rel="external">Multi-page link</a>

Comment: @ChinnuR it doesn't work and also when click the add it didn't add the details to my db...

Comment: i solved this issue using this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-javascript/2865546#2865546

Comment: @ChinnuR thank you..i solved the issue..

Comment: Great !  `$(location).attr('href');`

Comment: @ChinnuR just replace this window.location.hash; to $(location).attr('href');

Comment: data is plural for datum. there is no such word as "datas"

Comment: @Arut if you have solved your question then please post your answer and select it below for the benefit of people with this problem in the future (plus you get rep) :)

Comment: @jamesj please see my post i answered it..

Comment: @Arut You can post your own answer and select it. More rep for you and it makes it easier for people with the same problem to find the answer in future :)

Comment: @jamesj i posted here as a answer if i get any upvotes then i accept that answer. Why i mention that link means somepeoples may downvote it is alredy there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution using following method

```
var loc = $(location).attr('href');
if (loc.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
    var url = loc.substr(loc.indexOf("?") + 1, loc.length);
    listId = url.split("=")[1];
```

it will be helpful for someone like me.

I solved my issue using this link      [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-javascript/2865546#2865546)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this javascript works the same way as javascript on a traditional browser here ..

Judging by the comments in the code, it looks like you're expecting the hash to hold the query string, perhaps ?

The hash only holds what's after the hash in a url

eg

www.this.com/apage.html?firstval=value&anothervalue=45#locationinpage

in this url,

window.locationhash will equal "#locationinpage"

but

window.locaton.search will equal "?firstval=value&anothervalue=45"

That is : the query string excluding the part after the hash

perhaps you need window.locaton.search instead, or as well ?